Unable to make post requset in python if secure flag and http only flag are set to false
I am making a post request using request module in python
response = requests.post(
    https://example.com/addCategory,
    cookies=request_cookie,
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
    proxies=proxies,
    verify=False)

This code is working and I am able to add category when ever session cookie attribure secure flag and HttpOnly flag is set to true by the server, but whenever secure and HTTP only is set to false by the server. I am unable to add the category as request fails
Tried looking for documentaion and other sources did'nt get any solution.

HttpOnly | OWASP Foundation
